# Decompiled code with .Net reflector has some unicode character

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, decompiling, .net-reflector

I have decompile some library with `.Net reflector`. But there is some Korean alphabet in it instead of functions.
Can I replace theme to English?
Those are like this:

```
if (catalogs == null)
                {
                    catalogs = new List<ComposablePartCatalog>();
                    catalogs.Add(蠒Ṃ슠厥荖乨Ὗὠ.쏼㗩≕調藀崥ᄀ(眞౅赲舚モ瑮.෬隁鼥ⵡﻹ㖒烚░(甊퇌ꢊꖽ፠䰷橝.뺛㸦ݑ胘믑�跷绑(typeof(Bootstrapper).TypeHandle))));
                    catalog = ꡗゴᎇ�碶㥝.⎑⧌略깫㈠떑惟컾(catalogs);
                }
                else
                {
                    catalog = ꡗゴᎇ�碶㥝.⎑⧌略깫㈠떑惟컾(catalogs);
                }
```

Comment: That's because library was obfuscated to prevent you from decompiling it and easily restoring original source code. So those characters are not actually meaningful and so cannot be translated.

Comment: @Evk thats not entirely true, in MSIL you can even use characters like **<** or **>** to name specific variables which isn't allowed in C#, but the compiler still does this anyway, so in MSIL this might be valid, but as stated not in C#.

Comment: @SebastianL but I don't say it's invalid. I just say you cannot get meaningful english names from that, because those names are just random set of symbols without any meaning.

Comment: @Evk Tnx. So it`s obfuscated with developer?

Comment: @KarimPazoki if you mean obfuscated _by_ developer then yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Briefly from comments: 
This code is obfuscated by developer. So those characters are not actually meaningful and so cannot be translated.

> manual obfuscation is the deliberate act of creating obfuscated code, i.e. source or machine code that is difficult for humans to understand. Like obfuscation in natural language, it may use needlessly roundabout expressions to compose statements. Programmers may deliberately obfuscate code to conceal its purpose (security through obscurity) or its logic

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can see, your .dll file was proteted using *Obfuscation*. But that's none of a problem, we will d**eo-obfuscate** it ok ? Download [DE4DOT right here](https://github.com/0xd4d/de4dot/releases) on the github release page and simply **drag and drop** your file on the binary file of DE4DOT.
The output shall not be obfuscated anymore.

Comment: Why downvote ? My reply is objective and I give practical advices with direct link to an open source repo